# Trying to plot a model line in R but it has to many dimensions for abline

Tags: r, plot, glm

I have a binomial GLM run using proportions as the response variable and and multiple variables

```
glm(formula = GalFailNo3 ~ treatment * diameter1 * foundress, 
family = quasibinomial, data = FigDatNo3)
```

I want to be able to plot the regression line but I am not sure how as I have only ever plotted simple lm models using abline. this is the data below in csv

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KXwQhH5kwQZVNtc0tieXBaSE0/view?usp=sharing

the problem is this model has 8 dimensions and I haven't got a clue where to start, like what function or package will be useful.

any other info I need to present let me know please

I have tried to use the predict function with some dummy values but it doesn't appear to work.

or maybe there is another way to visualise models that I don't know about?

Comment: `predict` will work, but you have to decide what you want to plot. `predict` will give the results on the link scale rather than the response scale by default.

Comment: Please include all the relevant information in your question. Linking to data  renders the question useless once you (re)move data from your folder. Simulate some data and present the code you're using to estimate the model (check) and predict the values. A tip: plot `GalFailNo3 ~ diameter | treatment` and mapping `foundress` to color, size or shape, depending on what the variable is (discrete, continuous).